# Is there a google script I can create so every row in my spreadsheet will copy to a new and separate sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am a teacher trying to create a cookbook from submissions made in google forms.  These submissions are all organized in google sheets. I am hoping someone can help me with a code so that every row (columns B-H) in the spreadsheet (every recipe) is copied to a separate sheet/tab. I would like the tab to be named after the recipe name (column D). The assignment is ongoing until the end of the school year so more submissions will be entered. I have been working on this script but I am getting an error when I try to save so I don't think I am successful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function makeTabs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var last = sheet.getLastRow();//identifies the last active row on the sheet
  //loop through the code until each row creates a tab.
  for(var i=0; i<last; i++){
    var tabName = sheet.getRange(i+1,4).getRange(i++,i+8);//get the range in column A and get the value.
    var create = ss.insertSheet(tabName);//create a new sheet with the value
```

Comment: I recommend that you take a little time and effort to describe what your trying to accomplish in a little greater detail.   If possible get another teacher to read it before you post it.  Try asking a teacher who teaches writing.

Comment: By the way, it's not a good idea to use lastRow for getting your data.  It's much better to use the event object from the submission trigger.  It provides you with two sources of data. One is e.namedValues and the other is e.values.  They both contain data from the current submission.  If you keep the data in the other sheet up to date then you won't have to copy it.

Comment: If you provide a good description of what you currently have already submitted and how you wish to transfer it to the recipes page, then we can help you write a script to accomplish what you require.

Comment: I agree in all the items pointed out by @Cooper. You could improve your description for us to be able to support you in your code. I understood the basic requirement to copy each row data to a separate individual sheet. But what will happen on your original sheet? Should the row data copied be deleted in your main sheet? or should it retain there?.But if you decided to use [form submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers) then you don't need to read your main sheet to create different sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you get started:

```
function myFunction() {
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  let values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getValues();
  let stepDescription = "";
  for(let row = 1; row < values.length; row++ ){
    let recipe = values[row];
    let name = recipe[1];
    let tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet(name);
    let newRow = 1;
    for(let step = 2; step < recipe.length; step++){
      stepDescription = recipe[step];
      tab.getRange(newRow, 1).setValue(stepDescription);
      newRow++;
    }
  }
}
```